# FFmpeg is creating invalid Output when using exotic Resolutions

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to encode and mux raw YUV frames into a .mp4 file. This worked great until I tried to use more exotic resolution like 1440x1080:
[image]

After checking my code and updating FFmpeg to the newest nightly build I, i created this mcve:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
}

#define STREAM_PIX_FMT AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P

using namespace std;

struct FFmpegEncoder {
    AVStream *avStream;
    AVFormatContext *avFormatContext;
    AVOutputFormat *avOutputFormat;
    AVCodecContext *avCodecContext;
    AVCodec *avCodec;

    int64_t nextFrameIndex = 0;
    AVFrame *frame;

    void open(int width, int height, int fps, const char* path);
    virtual void encode(AVFrame* frame, int frameLength);
    virtual void close();

    FFmpegEncoder();
};

void fill_yuv_image3(unsigned char **pict, int frame_index, int width, int height) {
    int x, y, i;
    i = frame_index;

    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
            pict[0][y * width + x] = x + y + i * 3;

    for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++) {
            pict[1][y * (width / 2) + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
            pict[2][y * (width / 2) + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
        }
    }
}

void FFmpegEncoder::open(int width, int height, int fps, const char* filename) {
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avFormatContext, NULL, NULL, filename);
    avOutputFormat = avFormatContext->oformat;
    avCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    avStream = avformat_new_stream(avFormatContext, NULL);
    avStream->id = avFormatContext->nb_streams - 1;
    avCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(avCodec);

    avCodecContext->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    avCodecContext->bit_rate = width * height * fps;
    avCodecContext->width = width;
    avCodecContext->height = height;
    avStream->time_base.den = fps;
    avStream->time_base.num = 1;
    avCodecContext->time_base = avStream->time_base;
    avCodecContext->gop_size = 15;
    avCodecContext->pix_fmt = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
    avCodecContext->thread_count = 16;

    if (avFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
        avCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }

    avcodec_open2(avCodecContext, avCodec, NULL);

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->format = avCodecContext->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = avCodecContext->width;
    frame->height = avCodecContext->height;
    av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);

    avcodec_parameters_from_context(avStream->codecpar, avCodecContext);
    av_dump_format(avFormatContext, 0, filename, 1);

    avio_open(&avFormatContext->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    avformat_write_header(avFormatContext, NULL);
}

void FFmpegEncoder::encode(AVFrame* frame, int _frameLength) {
    AVPacket* pkt = new AVPacket();

    av_init_packet(pkt);

    frame->pts = nextFrameIndex++;

    avcodec_send_frame(avCodecContext, frame);

    if (avcodec_receive_packet(avCodecContext, pkt) == 0) {
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, avCodecContext->time_base, avStream->time_base);
        pkt->stream_index = avStream->index;
        av_write_frame(avFormatContext, pkt);
    }
    delete pkt;
}

void FFmpegEncoder::close() {
    av_write_trailer(avFormatContext);
    avcodec_free_context(&avCodecContext);
    av_frame_free(&frame);

    if (!(avOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        avio_closep(&avFormatContext->pb);
    }
    avformat_free_context(avFormatContext);
}

FFmpegEncoder::FFmpegEncoder() {

}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FFmpegEncoder encoder;
    int width = 1440; //when using 1920 here it works fine
    int height = 1080;

    encoder.open(width, height, 30, "testoutput.mp4");
    int frameCount = 200;

    //Allocate testframes
    unsigned char*** frames = new unsigned char**[frameCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
        frames[i] = new unsigned char*[3];
        frames[i][0] = new unsigned char[width * height];
        frames[i][1] = new unsigned char[(width / 2) * (height / 2)];
        frames[i][2] = new unsigned char[(width / 2) * (height / 2)];
        fill_yuv_image3(frames[i], i, width, height);
    }

    AVFrame* avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    avFrame->format = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
    avFrame->width = width;
    avFrame->height = height;
    av_frame_get_buffer(avFrame, 0);

    //start encoding
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
        memcpy(avFrame->data[0], frames[i][0], width * height);
        memcpy(avFrame->data[1], frames[i][1], (width / 2) * (height / 2));
        memcpy(avFrame->data[2], frames[i][2], (width / 2) * (height / 2));
        encoder.encode(avFrame, 0);
    }
    encoder.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I know the code is still long but I even removed error handling to reduce its length.

**Please Note:**

- The output file is playable in all common players and looks the same
- When changing the resolution width to a more common one like 1280, 1600, 1920 the output looks perfectly fine
- I tried the following codecs: MPEG4, x264, openh264

Creating a file with the same dimensions using ffmpeg from the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i valid1920x1080.mp4 -s 1440x1080 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Is creating valids outputs, so it must be possible.

Which setting is wrong? I looked at the outdated [muxing](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.0/doc_2examples_2muxing_8c-example.html) and [encoding](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.0/doc_2examples_2decoding_encoding_8c-example.html) examples but couldn't explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Switch to `av_frame_get_buffer(avFrame, 32)` and check.

Comment: @Gyan Thx for the suggestion. The output keeps the same when using `av_frame_get_buffer(avFrame, 32)` with a width of 1440.

Comment: Try some non-standard width which is a multiple of 64.

Comment: @Gyan I tried 1472 and the output looks good now

Comment: Since the stride has to be 32-aligned, and the chroma is half-width, your planes 1 and 2 should have width which is a multiple of 32. In case, it is not, increase it. But keep your declared width the same and try. Only change the buffer sizes.

Comment: Wow, this is working. This is how I changed my code: https://pastebin.com/58pEB9NP Feel free to use it if you want to post an answer. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All planes of a frame sent to the encoder are aligned to a linesize which is a multiple of 32 (or greater). For format YUV420P, the chroma planes have width half that of the luma component. So, for a frame width of 1440, the chroma width is 720, and 720 % 32 != 0. But the U and V buffers have been assigned a naive size of width x height. So when `memcpy` is carried out, the first `(width/2 - (width/2) % 32)` elements of the next row are copied into the stride-padded elements of the frame sent to the encoder. This will produce a visual distortion as seen in the Q images.

The correction is to pad the raw chroma plane buffers to the stride-aligned sizes. The OP's modifications, as linked in comments, are

```
void fill_yuv_imageY(unsigned char **pict, int frame_index, int width, int height) {
    int x, y, i;
    i = frame_index;

    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
            pict[0][y * width + x] = x + y + i * 3;
}

void fill_yuv_imageUV(unsigned char **pict, int frame_index, int halfWidth, int height) {
    int x, y, i;
    for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < halfWidth; x++) {
            pict[1][y * halfWidth + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
            pict[2][y * halfWidth + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
        }
    }
}

int roundUp(int numToRound, int multiple){
    if (multiple == 0)
        return numToRound;

    int remainder = numToRound % multiple;
    if (remainder == 0)
        return numToRound;

    return numToRound + multiple - remainder;
}

//Allocating test frames
unsigned char*** frames = new unsigned char**[frameCount];
for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    frames[i] = new unsigned char*[3];
    frames[i][0] = new unsigned char[width * height];
    fill_yuv_imageY(frames[i], i, width, height);
    frames[i][1] = new unsigned char[roundUp(width / 2, 32) * (height / 2)];
    frames[i][2] = new unsigned char[roundUp(width / 2, 32) * (height / 2)];
    fill_yuv_imageUV(frames[i], i, roundUp(width / 2, 32), height);
}
```